# why the sleep statement produces this result for our embedded ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, linux

We are testing thread coperation for our embedded ruby. We have a C ruby extension implementented the following methods

```
1. longRunningMethod()
2. shortRunningMethod().
```

Here is a code for the checking the thread cooperation

//file
test.rb

```
require 'mymodule'

$a = 0;
obj = MyModule::MyClass.new
t1 = Thread.new{$a = obj.veryLongRunningOperation(); puts "doneLong"}
sleep 1
$a = obj.shortOperation()
puts "doneShort"
t1.join
```

We have ensured that the longRunningMethod takes more than 1sec(5sec) for execution using nested for loops
As per our understanding, the shortRunningMethod should be completed first and then longRunningMethod.

However we observed this only when we did not have any sleep command.
But when we introduced the "sleep 1" statement. The longRunningMethod gets executed first and then shortRunningMethod

Anyone would give us the pointers as to why the sleep statement produces this result?

[We are using ruby 1.8.6] Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Threads in Ruby 1.8 do not use native OS threading mechanisms. All Ruby threads, are actually run within one native thread (no parallel execution).

Your C methods are atomic, so that thread scheduler waits until they return, before switching Ruby threads. That's why once it starts doing `longRunningMethod` before it gets to `shortRunningMethod` it does nothing else until it's finished. You're experiencing what is called a 'thread starvation'.

One way to avoid it, is to implement your `longRunningMethod` in such a way, so that it periodically calls `sleep` itself.

Comment: thanks very much for your ans. Can u tell me that what is atomic methods and does c has a atomic method(I found objective c has atomic methods)??

Comment: It's atomic in that once it starts execution, Ruby can't stop or suspend it. It need to be executed in its entirety before control returns to Ruby.

Comment: i have a question that why we get expected results??(the shortRunningMethod completed first and then longRunningMethod.) when we remove the sleep function call.

Comment: Because thread scheduler does not start `t1` thread immediately (even though it is in `runnable` state). Why exactly? This is probably left to the implementation of scheduler. When you add `sleep 1` it puts the main thread to sleep, and so the scheduler has no other choice than to start thread `t1`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the thread automatically started as soon as it is created? In Java, one has to call `t1.start()` explicitly to start the thread. Maybe it's the same in Ruby.

`t1.join` could have the extra functionality that it chcks whether the thread has started already, and if it hasn't, it is started.